# Enumerate inorder in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree, dcg, failure-slice

I'm trying to "reverse" an inorder traversal by turning the inorder list back into BSTs.

BSTs has the predicate form `node(Value,Left,Right)` or `leaf`, so the empty tree is just `leaf`, a tree with one node is `node(_,leaf,leaf)`.

Given the predicate `enumerate_bst(Elems,Bst)`, the goal is to match `Bst` to all possibilities of the inorder list `Elems`. For example (note [setof/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)):

```
?- setof(Bst,enumerate_bst([],Bst),Enum).
Enum = [leaf].

?- setof(Bst,enumerate_bst([1,2],Bst),Enum).
Enum = [
    node(1, leaf, node(2, leaf, leaf)),
    node(2, node(1, leaf, leaf), leaf)
].

?- setof(Bst,enumerate_bst([1,2,3],Bst),Enum).
Enum = [
    node(1, leaf, node(2, leaf, node(3, leaf, leaf))),
    node(1, leaf, node(3, node(2, leaf, leaf), leaf)),
    node(2, node(1, leaf, leaf), node(3, leaf, leaf)),
    node(3, node(1, leaf, node(2, leaf, leaf)), leaf),
    node(3, node(2, node(1, leaf, leaf), leaf), leaf)
].
```

*What I tried to do:*

I already have a predicate that matches a given BST to it's inorder list:

```
inorder(leaf,[]).
inorder(node(X,L,R),Elems) :-
  inorder(L,Elems_L),
  inorder(R,Elems_R),
  append(Elems_L,[X],Tmp),
  append(Tmp,Elems_R,Elems).
```

I tried to use it in reverse by putting in a list instead, but this only returned one result, I'm not exactly sure why.

*What I'm currently trying to do*

I'm trying to use the native predicate [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) in reverse, but can't fully decide how this will be done.

Any ideas as to the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reverse, your program does not terminate. Consider:

```
?- inorder(Tree, []).
   Tree = leaf
;  loops.
```

We would expect that it just shows this only solution and then stops.
The actual reason is the following fragment of your program - a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). No need to look any further than that. In other words, no need to understand `append/3` at all.

```
?- inorder(Tree, []), false.

inorder(leaf,[]) :- false.
inorder(node(X,L,R),Elems) :-
   inorder(L,Elems_L), false.
   inorder(R,Elems_R),
   append(Elems_L,[X],Tmp),
   append(Tmp,Elems_R,Elems).
```

First, this fragment needs to terminate (and fail). Only then you may consider termination of the entire program. Within this fragment, the second argument (`Elems`) is completely ignored! The first goal that would be interested in it is the very last one (`append(Tmp,Elems_R,Elems)`).

A naive way out would be to reorder the goals, putting the two `append/3` goals first. [That works](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti?texta=inorder(leaf%2C%5B%5D).%0D%0Ainorder(node(X%2CL%2CR)%2CElems)%20%3A-%0D%0A%20%20append(Tmp%2CElems_R%2CElems)%2C%0D%0A%20%20append(Elems_L%2C%5BX%5D%2CTmp)%2C%0D%0A%20%20inorder(L%2CElems_L)%2C%0D%0A%20%20inorder(R%2CElems_R).%0D%0A%0D%0Aappend(%5B%5D%2C%20Xs%2C%20Xs).%0D%0Aappend(%5BX%7CXs%5D%2C%20Ys%2C%20%5BX%7CZs%5D)%20%3A-%0D%0A%20%20append(Xs%2C%20Ys%2C%20Zs).) (that is, it terminates for a ground second argument), but it is quite unsatisfying, as the program is now devoted to distributing elements of a list into trees *only*.

Here is a version that works [both ways](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti?texta=inorder%28Tree%2C+Xs%29+%3A-%0D%0A+++phrase%28inorder%28Tree%2C+Xs%2C%5B%5D%29%2C+Xs%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Ainorder%28leaf%2C+Vs%2CVs%29+--%3E%0D%0A+++%5B%5D.%0D%0Ainorder%28node%28X%2CL%2CR%29%2C+%5B_%7CVs0%5D%2CVs%29+--%3E%0D%0A+++inorder%28L%2C+Vs0%2CVs1%29%2C%0D%0A+++%5BX%5D%2C%0D%0A+++inorder%28R%2C+Vs1%2CVs%29.) as indicated by the termination condition:

> ```
> inorder(A,B)terminates_if b(A);b(B).
> ```

which states that `inorder/2` terminates if the first or the second argument is ground.

```
inorder(Tree, Xs) :-
   phrase(inorder(Tree, Xs,[]), Xs).

inorder(leaf, Vs,Vs) -->
   [].
inorder(node(X,L,R), [_|Vs0],Vs) -->
   inorder(L, Vs0,Vs1),
   [X],
   inorder(R, Vs1,Vs).
```

Comment: What is the `-->` syntax in this case?

Comment: It's a [tag:dcg]. Say `listing(inorder)` to see how it is expanded to a regular Prolog predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote a '[library](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/blob/master/when_.pl)' for this task. Using that:

```
:- use_module(carlo(snippets/when_)).

inorder(leaf,[]).
inorder(node(X,L,R),Elems) -:-
  inorder(L,Elems_L),
  inorder(R,Elems_R),
  append(Elems_L,[X],Tmp),
  append(Tmp,Elems_R,Elems).
```

then

```
?- inorder(T,[1,2,3]).
T = node(1, leaf, node(2, leaf, node(3, leaf, leaf))) ;
T = node(1, leaf, node(3, node(2, leaf, leaf), leaf)) ;
T = node(2, node(1, leaf, leaf), node(3, leaf, leaf)) ;
T = node(3, node(1, leaf, node(2, leaf, leaf)), leaf) ;
T = node(3, node(2, node(1, leaf, leaf), leaf), leaf) ;
false.
```

The only change to your code (apart the inclusion of the 'library') is the replacement of `:-` with `-:-`. I choosed the symbol to suggest bidirectionality...

Comment: Produces many inconsistencies, like `L=[_], T = node(A,node(B,leaf,leaf),leaf), inorder(T, L).` which has no solution and thus should rather fail.